# Forward declare nested stucture in base class

Tags: c++, oop

Suppose I have a base abstract class:

```
class Foo {
public:
    struct FooStruct;
    virtual FooStruct *DoFoo() = 0;
};
```

And now I would like to implement the `DoFoo` in `Bar` and also define the `FooStruct` inside it:

```
class Bar: public Foo {
public:
    struct FooStruct {
        int data;
    };
    FooStruct *DoFoo() {
        FooStruct *fs = new FooStruct;
        fs->data = 42;
        return fs;
    }
};
```

However, `g++` (in my case) recognizes `Foo::FooStruct` and `Bar::FooStruct` as two different structures and will complain about `invalid covariant type ...` because I redefine return type of a method.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You need to define `Foo::FooStruct`, too. The fact that you define `Bar::FooStruct` is immaterial.

Comment: You need a common base class for the returned value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your pupose is then to do something as:

```
Foo * my_foo = new Bar();
FooStruct * my_result = my_foo->DoFoo();
```

The problem is that to use `my_result` now, you must know that it is implicitely a `struct` that has been created by `Bar`. Hence, you should define your returned `struct` externaly to `Foo`

Answer (score 0):

You can not do what you are seemingly trying to do. Virtual functions should have the same static return type everywhere across the hierarchy, and Foo::FooStruct has nothing to do with Bar::FooStruct. What you seem to be craving is something like following:

```
// In Foo.h
struct FooStruct { virtual ~FooStruct() = default; }

class Foo {
public:
    virtual FooStruct* DoFoo() = 0;
    virtual ~Foo() = default;
};

// In Bar.h
struct DerivedFooStruct : FooStruct { };
struct Bar : public Foo {
    FooStruct* DoFoo() { return new DerivedFooStruct(); } // Never mind memory mgmt
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to create a monster that doesn't fit into the C++ type system.

Imagine someone is trying to use a `Foo` pointer polymorphically:

```
Foo* ptr = .... ; //getting the value from somewhere, e.g. an API call
??? result = ptr->DoFoo();
```

What's going to be the type of the return value? The compiler doesn't know it.

Use a common base class for the struct you're going to return. A forward declaration won't cut it.